# Запрос(get/post) на сервер в background

Tags: ios, swift, post, get, background

Приветствую. Мне необходимо отправлять (получать) данные на сервер в фоне (в режиме background). Для этого использую Background fetch. Ниже приведен код:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {  UIApplication.sharedApplication().setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {        
    sendInform()
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
}

func sendInform() {
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://dev.superpaperboys.com/aaapi/post.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "login=log&password=pas";
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)  
            {
                data, response, error in
                if error != nil
                {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }   
                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            }
            task.resume()
   }
```

Бывает, что запрос выполняется и я вижу

```
responseString = Optional({"login":"log","password":"pas"})
```

Бывает, что запрос не выполняется до тех пор, пока я не зайду в приложение.
Иногда возникает следующая ошибка :

```
error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x15ee81630 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://dev.superpaperboys.com/aaapi/post.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://dev.superpaperboys.com/aaapi/post.php, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})
```

Не могу увидеть закономерность. Может кто сталкивался с данной проблемой. Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: насчет того, что фетч не выполняется: 1) убедитесь, что приложение действительно есть на бэкграунде 2) насколько я помню, бэкграунд фетч имеет минимальное время между фетчами что то типа 10 минут, может вы просто недостаточно долго ждете. насчет таймаута поставьте charles, посмотрите может действительно что то с сервером не так

Comment: я вывожу на экран сообщение, когда запускается performFetchWithCompletionHandler. Так что я вижу, когда  он запускается, в функцию sendInform я тоже захожу и останавливаюсь на task